# What are these pixeled-out places from the Endymion special?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

In the **Index-tan** special for the **Toaru Majutsu no Index: Endymion no Kiseki** movie, the following two images appear, pixelated-out, during a conversation about landmarks in Tokyo:

[image: a place]

[image: a different place]

What are these places?

Comment: How come they are blurred out?

Comment: @krikara Presumably the same reason that pop-culture references to things like brand-name goods get pixelated out. I don't really know what the reason for _that_ is, though. Conventional wisdom is that this happens to avoid trademark infringment and so forth, but I don't know what the actual answer is.

Answer (score 6):

The first place is the [**Asahi Beer Hall**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asahi_Beer_Hall) (i.e. the *Super Dry Hall*, スーパードライホール). (cf. [Google Street View](http://goo.gl/maps/vBOEc))

[image: the Asahi Beer Hall; image from Japanese Wikipedia]

The second is [**Saw, Sawing**](http://oldenburgvanbruggen.com/largescaleprojects/sawsawing.htm), an art installation by Claes Oldenburg located at the Tokyo International Exhibition Centre (aka Big Sight). (cf. [Google Street View](http://goo.gl/maps/QTBv0))

[image: Saw, Sawing; image from Oldenburg's website]